# error passing variables python web application with flask

Tags: python, function, web, flask

I am new in programming and I know that are useful things out there like wtforms for this, but I want to practice a little before dive into it.

The idea is to create a web app that register the user, and I think it is better to keep this logic apart from the application code.

**The problem is that I have this error message: 
*TypeError: register() takes 0 positional arguments but 3 were given*
I am confused because the function declaration has positional arguments, the code I wrote is:**

app code:

````py
@app.route("/register", methods=["POST", "GET"])
def register():
    if request.method =="POST":
        if not user_name or not password or not pass_confirm:
            return ("all fields are mandatory, also consider to active javaScript for a better expirience",404)
    user_name = request.form.get("user_name")
    password = request.form.get("password")
    pass_confirm = request.form.get("user_name")
    register(user_name, password, pass_confirm)
    return render_template("/register.html")```
````

in another file:

```py
def register(user_name, password, pass_confirm):
    if password != pass_confirm:
        return("Password and password confirmation must match")
```

Comment: The problem is the *other* `register` function doesn't have positional arguments. Maybe rename the one in the other file to `register_logic` or something.

Comment: Python does not support [function overloading](https://www.codementor.io/@arpitbhayani/overload-functions-in-python-13e32ahzqt). Consider giving one of the two functions a different name.

Comment: You are calling same function inside 'register' function (recursion). Make sure you are calling correct register, you need to import it if it is from another file. Example: 
import AnotherFile

AnotherFile.register(user_name, password, pass_confirm)

Comment: Thank you guys! All relevant points. I changed the called function name. =D tnx a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You used the function register with no arguments ,so try to rename it.

the code will be

@app.route("/register", methods=["POST", "GET"])

def reg():

````
if request.method =="POST":

    if not user_name or not password or not pass_confirm:

return ("all fields are mandatory, also consider to active javaScript for a better expirience",404)

user_name = request.form.get("user_name")

password = request.form.get("password")

pass_confirm = request.form.get("user_name")

register(user_name, password, pass_confirm)

return render_template("/register.html")```
````

## in another file:

````
    if password != pass_confirm:

        return("Password and password confirmation must match")```
````

Comment: Ow, I see..I used the same name for both functions. This solved the problem! Thank you! =D